# Is accidental "code injection" or execution possible with non-executable files

Tags: assembly, code-injection, machine-code

As a self-taught "programmer" I am not very clued up on the internal workings of software apart from it being translated to machine instructions by my compiler. As I started to familiarize myself with assembly language and machine instructions the following question came to mind:

> Is it possible to have a simple data file like a text file or bitmap (or anything for that matter) that have just the wrong combination of bytes that makes the computer crash as it is being read? With some files being billions of bytes I think the likelihood of a few consecutive bytes forming instructions are quite likely.

Obviously nothing intelligent will happen but maybe some combination of bytes may cause the instruction pointer to point in the wrong direction or just skip reading the rest of the file.

Maybe OS developers and compiler developers already dealt with this issue behind the scenes but one can not account for all that could go wrong, maybe some data could even pass through those contingencies.

I suppose this boils down to the same concept of having a troop of monkeys with typewriters producing Shakespeare, except that machine instructions are much shorter than Hamlet.

Comment: The likelihood of some random file having a valid [PE header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#/media/File:Portable_Executable_32_bit_Structure_in_SVG.svg) (or the corresponding header for whatever executable format your OS uses) is quite low, but certainly not impossible. If you ended up executing such a file you'd get undefined behavior; i.e. it could end up doing anything (crashing being a fairly likely outcome).

Comment: On  modern operating systems code and data are loaded into different parts of memory, and data is set to be non-executable. Partly as a protection against virus-code.

Comment: Just reading a file won't execute it. For that you actually need to ask the OS to execute it. You also need execute permission for the file.

Comment: A thing to understand about monkeys and playwrights is that in the time the universe is commonly theorized to exist and with monkeys filling the space that the universe is commonly theorized to occupy, the chance of monkeys typing "Taming of the Shrew" is an exceedingly bad bet even if one were given a googol to one odds. A very short set of instructions is within reason, but when you add in the required headers for an executable file (although a .COM file is an exception) then you have a better chance of finding a proton hidden somewhere in the universe than of randomly forming an executable.